# Convert a <input form> in a <a href

Tags: css, button, input, hyperlink, href

My code has

```
<input class="menu_button" type="submit" value="Log in">
<a href="register.php" class="menu_button">Register</a>
```

The a href is styled perfectly in my css while the input button with type = submit DOES NOT...

How could I change

Into a a href?

Here is a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/26tyd/

SEE HOW THE BUTTONS LOOK different. one higher up and smaller the other is perfect. Please help me figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS in the question.

Comment: its on jsfiddle and also the css is irrelevant to the question

Comment: The CSS is **not** irrelevant; it's a core part of the question. The basic problem is that the browser has a different default stylesheet for the two elements, and you're not overriding all those defaults. So we need to see what you are overriding. Please note that Stackoverflow encourages questions to include all relevant code in the question even if they are also in a separate linked page, because if someone else searches for for your question in the future, there's no guarantee that the external link will still work.

Comment: Form inputs are rendered different in most browsers, for instance Safari inputs look completely different than Chrome ones. So if you really care about an element looking the same as an `<a />` element, then I suggest not using a form input. In this case you could create another anchor that is your submit button and use a JS event handler to submit the form when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you need to style both elements the same?
Here's one solution:

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/26tyd/2/)**

```
.menu_button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -1px 0px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -1px 0px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -1px 0px 0px #000000;

    background-color:#000000;
    text-indent: 0;
    border: 1px solid #fa1e0f;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 12px/1 Arial;
    width: 58px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #33302f;
    padding: 5px 0;
    ouotline: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
}
/*this is needed for firefox and buttons */
.menu_button::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; padding: 0; outline: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
input[type=submit]{
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using height and width like you are currently doing you should use padding because then the text is vertically centred.

The reason that the is not being sent is because you are not currently using a form so you need to add a form tag around the stuff that you want in the form so you could use this:

```
<form action='#' method='get'>
    <input class="menu_button" type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/26tyd/3/

Comment: Another way to vertically align text to the middle of an element is by setting `line-height` to the height of the element and then setting `vertical-align:middle`. This only works for single lines of text.

Comment: THANKS TO EVERYONE THAT CONTRIBUTED! This helped sooo much

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add below code in your code:

```
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

And to adjust the hight and with I would sugegst you to play with "min-width" and "padding". As giving "Width" and "Height" can limit your button and if you have more test or padding the height and width will not let the background increase.

Please see the updated code:-

```
.menu_button {
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -1px 0px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -1px 0px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -1px 0px 0px #000000;
    background-color:#000000;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #fa1e0f;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #33302f;
    box-sizing: border-box; /*ADDED*/
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /*ADDED*/
    padding:5px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Created a fiddle too for you to  refer : http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/7NFvH/1/

Comment: sorry for the Typos :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
white-space: normal;
box-sizing: content-box;
```

The `input` tags are styled different by the user agent stylesheet than `a` tags.